# Случайные символы в с#

Tags: c#

Как заполнить двухмерный массив случайными символами?

Comment: @AresGod я пробывал) у меня почемуто выводит трёхзначные значения (110, 115,108 ....)

Comment: Что конкретно не получается? В таком виде вопрос скорее закроют чем ответят, приведите хотя бы фрагмент вашей попытки решить задачу с которым у вас возникла проблема

Comment: 100% уже были такие вопросы, почему нельзя просто погуглить? Или задать вопрос: «Пишу такое. Выводится такое. Помогите понять где ошибка», а не написать общий вопрос.

Comment: @AresGod: Посылать в гугл невежливо. Если вы можете найти ответ в гугле за минуту, запостите лучше ссылку на ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Вы вряд ли хотите реально случайный символ, т. к. среди них могут быть и иероглифы, и диакритика, и просто математические значки. Поэтому вам нужен набор символов, из которого вы будете получать их. Например, строка.

```
static string symbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Имея набор символов, легко выбрать из них случайный:

```
static Random r = new Random();
static char GetRandomChar()
{
    var index = r.Next(symbols.Length);
    return symbols[index];
}
```

Имея функцию, выдающую случайный символ, вы, думаю, самостоятельно сможете заполнить такими символами массив.